# How to delete entries that share similar pattern in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column that may contain entries like this:
abc.yahoo.com
efg.yshoo.com
hij.yahoo.com

I need to delete all the duplicates and LEAVE ONE ONLY as I don't need the others. Such command can be easily done if I know the second part (ex: yahoo.com) but my problem is that the part (yahoo.com) is not fixed. I may have entries such as:
abc.msn.com
efg.msn.com
hij.msn.com

And I want to treat all these cases at once. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post your table schema? What is your primary key column?

Comment: The primary key is Auto increment number. This field that contains the links is defined as unique.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you just want to take out the letters before the first `.` then group on the column:

```
DELETE a FROM tbl a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT   MIN(id) AS id
    FROM     tbl
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(column, LOCATE('.', column))
) b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Where `id` is your primary key column name, and `column` is the column that contains the values to group on.

This will also account for domains like `xxx.co.uk` where you have two parts at the end.

Make sure you have a backup of your current data or run this operation within a transaction (where you can `ROLLBACK;` if it didn't fit your needs).

**EDIT**: If after deleting the duplicates you want to replace the letters before the first `.` with `*`, you can simply use:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET column = CONCAT('*', SUBSTRING(column, LOCATE('.', column)))
```

Comment: yes, I want to remove the letters before the fist dot and replace these letters with * and make it a single record only because they are all similar except in this field. I hope you get what I mean?

Comment: What is 'a' in DELETE 'a' ?? Whenever I delete, I use delete from table1 without anything before from ?

Comment: @JuryA, see updated solution for updating the columns to put `*` before the first `.` after you deleted duplicates. And the `a` in the `DELETE` is necessary since we are using a JOIN in the delete statement (because we are referencing two tables, the DELETE must know which one to delete from).

Comment: Sorry, what I'm asking for is in one table only. It has a primary key auto_increment. Also, it has a unique column in the same table which is the column that contains the urls I'm concerned with. There is another table connected with this one, but the second one has foreign key on update and on delete cascade. But the whole issue is in one table only.

Comment: @JuryA, the DELETE is using a ***SELF***-join in order to find the minimum `id` of the `column` grouped by its contents after the first `.`. The `DELETE` statement is still only dealing with one table.

Comment: Bear with me please. I can't understand the `a` and `b`. In my case, what should I place instead of `a` and `b`?? `tbl` is my table that I'm working in.

Comment: @JuryA, you can leave those as just `a` and `b`. Those are just aliases for the table / subselect selections. You only need to change the name of `tbl` to your table name, `column` to the unique column storing your values, and `id` to the auto-incrementing primary key column. That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the duplicates you can use

```
DELETE FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT   MIN(id) AS id
    FROM     your_table 
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(col), '.', 2)
) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

If you need to create an UNIQUE constraint for that you can do the following

1.Add another field to hold the domain value

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN `domain` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

2.Update it with the correct values

```
UPDATE your_table set domain = REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(col), '.', 2));
```

3.Add the unique constraint

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE domain (domain);
```

4.Add before insert and before update trggers to set the domain column

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `your_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `your_table ` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    set new.domain = REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(new.col1), '.', 2));
END$$


CREATE TRIGGER `your_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `your_table ` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    set new.domain = REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(new.col1), '.', 2));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note: this assumes the domain is the last 2 words when separated by '.', it will not work for a domain such as ebay.co.uk . For that you will probably need to make a stored function which returns the domain for a given host and use it instead of `REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX...`.